# Can someone tell me why the new beta version of Xcode does not simulate io7 on an iphone 4/4s

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5

[image]Dumb Question:

I just downloaded the new version of Xcode Version 5.0 (5A11365j), and when I build an new Iphone app and go to

Products -> Destination -> Iphone ->

I see only iOS6 + iOS5.

Where the hell is iOS7???

I know that iPhone 4/4s are going to support iOS7, where is the simulator for it?

Thanks

[image]

UPDATE: I have attached an image for those that dont believe me

Comment: I am not seeing anything similar to what you have mentioned.

Comment: check at my image uploads and please remove the downvote

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a beta version.

Comment: OK - well where should it go ?

Comment: Are you completely sure that you have opened up XCode 5 and not an older version? That looks more like XCode 4 than 5.

Comment: XCode5-DP4 (plus I took a screen shot of the version). Xcode4 did not have an options for iOS7 either, but other menus below this do contain iOS7

Answer (score 3):

The problem I'm seeing is that you're selecting "iPhone", which I believe corresponds to the non-retina simulator which doesn't have support for iOS 7. You have to run in one of the retina simulators.

[image]

Comment: the previous beta version of Xcode supported it though ... when I select Retina 4-inch I am looking at some huge screen. I am positive before I update xCode (previous beta version) I was able to simulate a normal iPhone is iOS7 - any ideas ?

Comment: also - correct me if i am wrong - but Iphone4 (not 4s) is not retina and it is going to support iOS7

Comment: @JosephMisiti No clue. And no, the iPhone 4 has retina display.

Comment: Window -> Scale -> 50%

Comment: To expand on @0x7fffffff 's comment, per official announcements, no non-retina iPhones will be supported by iOS 7. I suspect that explains whatever the original poster is seeing.

Comment: OK - it seems like Pier fixed my issue - i am really dumb - sorry to waste you guys/girls time. thanks and close this stupid question :)

Comment: @Tommy, not quite true. the iPad 2 and iPad mini, both non-retina, are supported by iOS 7. However, no non-retina iPhones nor iPod touches are supported.